# Обновление виджета в GTK

Tags: c++, python, c, gtk, vala

Суть такова - я создаю виджет `Gtk.Notebook`. Дальше при нажатии определённой кнопки должна добавляться новая вкладка (кнопка уже есть и даже приконнекчена), однако вкладка не появляется, как и содержимое. Можно ли как-нибудь перерисовать виджет, или сделать с ним что-то ещё, чтоб вкладка отобразилась?

P. S. Можете давать примеры на C и Python. Ну и C++. Их я тоже пойму.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос Ваш обработчик нажатия кнопки, добавляющий вкладку. Постараюсь дома посмотреть, если ответов здесь не появится...

Comment: @SergeyPopov Я просто использую названиекнопки.clicked.connect(() => { notebook.append_page(информация вкладки) });

Comment: Без кода трудно чем-то помочь

Comment: покажите пример кода

Comment: @erl Весь код глядеть на гитхабе (handicraftsman/gtk-creator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поможет вам `notebook.show_all ();`

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Заработает - отпишусь.

Comment: Работает. Огромное спасибо)